# How to Move from Referenced libraries to src in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I Imported the Jar files through Build Path.Now the Classes are in Referenced libraries in eclipse.Now i have to move the classes from the Referenced libraries to the SRC Folder.How to Do it ???
Or can i directly import from jar to SRC folder ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the jar files in the libs folder of the android project. They will be automatically added to build path and you can use the classes they contain.

Comment: You just copy them in the libs folder and use them like any other Android class. In the src folder you just create your own classes which use the classes in jars by importing them. You don't copy or move the classes in the jar to src folder, you just use them after you copyed the jar in the libs folder of yoir project.